# Using require.resolve in webpack config yields runtime error: "The provided value"..."is not an absolute path!"

Tags: javascript, webpack, exports-loader

I am attempting to use the `exports-loader` with my webpack config, but I'm running into an issue when trying to configure it.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('./src/globals.js'),
                use: 'exports-loader?file,parse=helpers.parse'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**./src/globals.js**

```
var file = 'blah.txt'
var helpers = {
    test: function() { console.log('test something'); },
    parse: function() { console.log('parse something'); }
}
```

**./src/index.js**

```
import { file } from './globals.js'
console.log('the file', file);
```

My application builds fine, but when I attempt to run it I get:

> WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.module.rules[0].test should be one of these:
>
>   - configuration.module.rules[0].test: The provided value "./src/globals.js" is not an absolute path!

To be completely clear, I understand the difference between an absolute and a relative path, and I know that the value I'm using is a relative path. My confusion is two-fold:

1. `require.resolve` allows relative paths, so why can I not use it
   here?
2. If I cannot use a relative path, how can I refer to that file otherwise?

I tried using an absolute path for the `test` property like so:

`test: require.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/globals.js'))`

But I get this error when I attempt to run:

> Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/my-app/dist/src/globals.js

So I'm stuck. How can I properly configure this loader to reference that file appropriately?

Comment: Did you just try: `test: path.join(__dirname, 'src/globals.js')` ?

Comment: That allows me to build and run, but `file` is undefined in my `./src/index.js` console.log statement. So I'm still not sure it's configured properly...

Comment: As far as I know, `test` basically expects a regex expression, so any string with a valid file path should be ok, so you don't explicitly need `require.resolve` for `test` to work. Now, apart from that, I don't know why your project is not bundling as expected. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. New question posted to follow up on the remaining part of this question.

Comment: There is something I don't find clear in your question: you're just trying to get `webpack-exports-loader` to work in your regular .js files? Or is it something more?

Answer (score 0):

### Getting `exports-loader` to work

[Exports loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) is a webpack loader that allows to dynamically add `exports` sentences to javascript files loaded with it. For instance, your `globals.js` file does not have any `export` in it, only the `file` and `helpers` variables, yet with `exports-loader` it can work *as if* it had `export` clauses.

#### Loading webpack  loaders

Basically, to use a loader we must to provide a `test` and an `use` clauses. The `test` can be a regex, an array or an object, and basically it decides which files will use certain loaders.

The `use` clause decides which loaders will be applied to the files that match the `test` regex.

In this case, we should -for instance- instruct webpack to load `globals.js` with `exports-loader`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /globals.js/,
        use: 'exports-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is -afaik- the most common way to use loaders. Webpack, however, has a lot of configuration options and different valid syntaxes.

Once we do this, when webpack finds a `require` or an `import` agains a `globals.js` file, it will use the `exports-loader`.

On other hand, `exports-loader` works by modifying the `require` calls to instruct it how to extract variables in the required file. As in their docs:

*file.js*

```
const file = 'foo';
```

*app.js*

```
const file = require('exports-loader?file!./file.js');
console.log(file); // foo
```

So, basically you need two things to get `exports-loader` to work:

1. Use `require` or `import` with their special syntax.
2. Load the loader in the `webpack.config.js` as usual (they skip this in their documentation).

Instead, you're trying to use this specific `exports-loader` syntax in your `webpack.config.js` file, and then using it with `import`.

So, bad news are that `exports-loader` need some special formatting in every `require` or `import` statement to do its *magic*. You just cannot specify this in your config file as you are trying (or, at least, I don't know how to).

So, to get it to work, you need to:

- Fix your `webpack.config.js` as stated above.
- change your `index.js` file so it uses the `exports-loader` *magic*:

```
import file from 'exports-loader?file!./deps.js'
console.log('the file', file);
```

Comment: Sergeon, see Webpack's own example of `exports-loader` that *does* use the webpack config file: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#global-exports. However, I was unable to get this to work, and asked that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106256/why-does-the-exports-loader-example-in-webpacks-documentation-not-work#

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, there appear to be 2 distinct ways to use `exports-loader`: (1) via webpack config file (webpack.config.js), and (2) "inline", via the `import` method you described. I was indeed able to get this to work by removing *all* `exports-loader` config from my `webpack.config.js`, and using *only* `import file from 'exports-loader?file!./globals.js`. So to sum up, using the plugin inline appears to work while using the file configuration approach does not.

Comment: In their github page, there is not any documentation about the global configuration way. Maybe you can get it to work if you open an issue there, so: 1) they improve their docs 2) they suggest you how to do this. I will explore if I can get the global config way to work