# Why does the "exports-loader" example in Webpack's documentation not work?

Tags: javascript, webpack, exports-loader

Webpack provides the example below in its [shimming documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming). In the [global exports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#global-exports) portion of that page, it gives the following example.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('globals.js'),
                use: exports-loader?file,parse=helpers.parse
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**./src/globals.js**

```
var file = 'blah.txt';
var helpers = {
    test: function() { console.log('test something'); },
    parse: function() { console.log('parse something'); }
};
```

But when I attempt to build, I get:

```
ERROR in ./webpack.config.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'globals.js' in '/workspace/my-app'
```

Why is `globals.js` not resolving, and why does the example in their documentation assume it will? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Because you didn't add the imports-loader `{
          test: require.resolve('index.js'),
          use: 'imports-loader?this=>window'
-       }` - check the `rules: []` in the example webpack config

Comment: That just gives a second error like the first: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'index.js' in '/workspace/my-app'`. Besides, I don't want to make `this === window` in my index.js entry file. I feel like that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Getting this to work with a global `exports-loader` configuration

I have this working with the following setup:

**src/deps.js** // this file just declare a global `file` variable

```
const file = 'this is the file';
```

**src/app.js** // entry point of the webpack bundle. It `import`'s `deps.js` (even if `deps.js` does not have an `export` statement, thanks to `export-loader`):

```
import file from './deps.js'
console.log(file);
```

**webpack.config.js** // webpack configuration file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/app.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /deps.js/,
        use: 'exports-loader?file',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json** // so we can run webpack locally to the project

```
{
  "name": "exports-loader-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

With this setup, assuming `webpack.config.js`, `package.json` and `src/` are in the root of the project, do:

`$ npm run webpack`

To bundle the scripts, then:

`$ node dist/main.js` to check that the `file` variable is being loaded (to load this in a browser will do the same).

### Getting this to work with an `import` specific configuration.

(this comes from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106172/4166367)).

In order to do so, you need to `use` just the `exports-loader`, without any further configuration when you load it in the `webpack.config.js`:

`use: 'exports-loader',`

And then specify the variables to wrap in an `export` clause in every `import` statement:

`import file from 'exports-loader?file!./deps.js'`

### Why the `require.resolve()` syntax is not working?

I really don't know. The `test` clause expects a regex as far as I know (that's why it is called `test` in fact, because of the `test` method of regex's in javascript) and I'm not used to other kind of valid syntaxes. I see that in your snippet:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('globals.js'),
                use: exports-loader?file,parse=helpers.parse
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The `use` value does not have string quotes. I wonder if this is broking the config and then you get a misleading error, I don't know. I actually believe you just didn't paste the quotes when copy and pasting to stack overflow.